# Error sending object to API using angular, registration method with template string and post method to server

Tags: angular, typescript, api-design

I created a registration service in my angular application but I came across an error that puzzled me, I've done some research but I still don't understand the reason for the error even though I've already solved it, when the parameter 'pessoaUsuaria' is without the {} I receive the object in a way that my API returns 200 making the registration effective, but when I use the curly braces I get a return of 500 but looking at the object it looks the same and this took me a long time to figure out, maybe it's a silly doubt but I really wanted to understand why this happens, I'll leave some code below and thanks for your help!

```
import { FormularioService } from './../../core/services/formulario.service';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { UnidadeFederativa } from 'src/app/core/types/type';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-base',
  templateUrl: './form-base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-base.component.scss']
})
export class FormBaseComponent implements OnInit{
  cadastroForm!: FormGroup;
  estadoControl = new FormControl<UnidadeFederativa | null>(null, Validators.required);
  @Input() perfilComponent!: boolean;
  @Output() acaoClique: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private formularioService: FormularioService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cadastroForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      nome: [null, Validators.required],
      nascimento: [null, [Validators.required]],
      cpf: [null, [Validators.required]],
      cidade: [null, Validators.required],
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      senha: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      genero: ['outro'],
      telefone: [null, Validators.required],
      estado: this.estadoControl,
      confirmarEmail: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      confirmarSenha: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      aceitarTermos: [null, [Validators.requiredTrue]]
    });
    this.formularioService.setCadastro(this.cadastroForm)
  }

  executarAcao() {
    this.acaoClique.emit();
  }
}
```

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { PessoaUsuaria } from '../types/type';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CadastroService {

  private apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  cadastrar(pessoaUsuaria: PessoaUsuaria): Observable<PessoaUsuaria> {
    return this.http.post<PessoaUsuaria>(`${this.apiUrl}/auth/cadastro`, ***pessoaUsuaria***);
  }
}
```

```
import { PessoaUsuaria } from 'src/app/core/types/type';
import { CadastroService } from './../../core/services/cadastro.service';
import { FormularioService } from './../../core/services/formulario.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cadastro',
  templateUrl: './cadastro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cadastro.component.scss']
})
export class CadastroComponent {
  perfilComponent = false;

  constructor (
    private formularioService: FormularioService,
    private cadastroService: CadastroService
  ) {}

  cadastrar() {
    const FormCadastro = this.formularioService.getCadastro()

    if(FormCadastro?.valid) {
      const novoCadastro = FormCadastro.getRawValue() as PessoaUsuaria;
      console.log(novoCadastro)
      this.cadastroService.cadastrar(novoCadastro).subscribe({
        next: (value) => {
          console.log('Cadastro realizado com sucesso!', value)
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.log('Erro ao realizar cadastro!', err)
        }
      })
    }
    
  }
}
```

[err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HS5Y.png)

error happens when I use this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { PessoaUsuaria } from '../types/type';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CadastroService {

  private apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  cadastrar(pessoaUsuaria: PessoaUsuaria): Observable<PessoaUsuaria> {
    return this.http.post<PessoaUsuaria>(`${this.apiUrl}/auth/cadastro`, { pessoaUsuaria });
  }
}
```

instead:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { PessoaUsuaria } from '../types/type';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CadastroService {

  private apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  cadastrar(pessoaUsuaria: PessoaUsuaria): Observable<PessoaUsuaria> {
    return this.http.post<PessoaUsuaria>(`${this.apiUrl}/auth/cadastro`, pessoaUsuaria );
  }
}
```

Comment: Since this `pessoaUsuaria` is an object, you don't need to add the `{}` as the HttpClient will post the request with body. You can check the differences between with/without the `{}`,  how the request is sent via DevTools > Newtork > Find the sent request and read the request payload. I suspect when you send the request with `{ pessoaUsuaria }`, the request body will be `{ pessoaUsuaria: { /* pessoaUsuaria key-value pair */ } } ` which is different compare to `{ /* pessoaUsuaria key-value pair */ }`.

Comment: Yes, it really does, when I use {} I see the following in the payload -> {"pessoaUsuaria":{"nome":.....}} and when I don't use it -> {"nome":....}! I was getting the error "SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed: user.nome" in my API terminal and I was stuck thinking that the problem was in the name, thanks a lot bro! @YongShun